# Error with ETL Excel Source to SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I'm trying to load records from an excel file using SSIS.  I created a dataflow, added an excel source, selected my file and sheet, then added a destintation source to SQL Server 2014 and tried to upload to a table I created  with the same column names as the excel sheet.  I keep getting this error.

Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Here is a link to my excel file from OneDrive: http://1drv.ms/1HIyb2J

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.

[Excel Source [20]] Error: There was an error with Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[chemical_name] on Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[Excel Source [20]] Error: The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[chemical_name]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[chemical_name]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC020902A.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 0 rows.
```

I've been following along this fix here:  http://www.bradleyschacht.com/excel-source-the-output-column-failed-becuase-truncation-occured/

But after changing the chemical_name output column's length to `300` (my largest column is 275) in the `advanced editor`, the error was still produced.

**WORKAROUND**

Something that actually got it to work was setting `TruncationRowDisposition` from `RD_FailComponent` to `RD_IgnoreFailure`.  Although I don't think this is a good idea and I'd rather find an actual fix for the error.

Comment: You have to have not only the same column names but the same datatypes and the size has to be big enough to fit the data, SSIS does no implicit conversion.  Excel fields show up as nvarchar or numeric and they are based generally on the fist few rows of the file which is often a problem for things like partnumbers where some are numeric and some are alpha and some are alphanumeric. There is also likely a more specific error if you look for it on the progress tab.

Comment: Look for a more specific error in the `execution results` tab when the package runs.    At least find out which task/component is failing.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys.  I added the execution errors to the original question.  It seems some of the values in my `chemical_name` column are too large.  So I changed `nvarchar(50)` to `nvarchar(MAX)` in my table design from SQL Server. Also, added a data conversion transformation, changing all the columns to `Unicode string[DT_WSTR]` with length `255`, but it still gave me an error.  I think some of the chemical name titles are very large. I think I need to parse the data and truncate all the values that are over

Comment: @HLGEM hmm it can't be that the size is of the column `chemical_name` is too small if I set it to `nvarchar(MAX)` because apparently thats 2GB of storage and ~1 billion characters, which I know I'm not using...

Comment: This might help: http://milambda.blogspot.com/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html